# Task Scheduler Library Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

A scheduled overnight task attempted to run but returned the operational code 'Launch Failure' - I think this was to do with a server connection going down. I can't remember what Task Scheduler said the status was but I ended up manually restarting the script. It appears to have run successfully, however in the history tab it says 'Action Completed' and 'Task completed' but the status shown in the Library is still 'Running' whereas it normally returns back to 'Ready Status'. Is there a reason it is still displaying Running, even though the history logs says it has completed?

Comment: What does `"I think this was to do with a server connection going down"` mean? What is your task doing? Have you verified that the task isn't actually still running by looking at the Task Manager, or ProcMon?

Comment: @MDMarra There is a connection to another server via a VPN to collect external data - i think it was this connection the dropped. I can still php.exe and php-cgi.exe processes in task manager but there is another task that runs every 5 mins which might be using it. I have very little experience with windows servers so will look into ProcMon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I right-clicked the task and selected 'End' and it reset the status back to 'Ready' so hopefully that will fix it!